# Replace string with unique value

Tags: python, pandas, str-replace

I am working with a dataset where one of the columns, 'PARNO', has values separated with '/'.

For example, 9644-54-3184/5544/2583. In reality this equates to 9644-54-3184, 9644-54-5544, 9644-54-2583.

I could do a simple .str.replace if this was the only column, but there are other rows with this formatting where the start of the PARNO is different to '9644-54-'

Example of the dataset is below and all of my code is below too, including what I've written to clean the other column values.

[image]

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

lc_subs['PARNO'] = lc_subs['PARNO'].str.replace('-','').str.replace('(','').str.replace(')','').str.replace(r'[A-Z]', '').str.replace(r'[a-z]', '').str.replace('.','').str.replace('#','')

lc_subs = (lc_subs.set_index(lc_subs.columns.drop('PARNO',1).tolist())
   .PARNO.str.split(',|;|&', expand=True)
   .stack()
   .reset_index()
   .rename(columns={0:'PARNO'})
   .loc[:, lc_subs.columns]
)
```

Is there a method to replace the '/' with the first 6 digits of that row?

The end goal is to have one number per per row, with no text or symbols, so I can do a spatial join on the PARNO column.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple way to replicate the number extension from their prefixes:

```
def expand(s):
    return s.replace("/",f",{s.rsplit('-',1)[0]}-").split(",")

print(expand("9644-54-3184/5544/2583"))

# ['9644-54-3184', '9644-54-5544', '9644-54-2583']
```

It works by replacing the "/" characters with a comma and the common prefix.  Then splitting on the comma.

So you get :

'9644-54-3184/5544/2583' --> '9644-54-3184,9644-54-5544,9644-54-2583'

which then splits (on the comma) as a list of expanded numbers:

['9644-54-3184', '9644-54-5544', '9644-54-2583']

*Note that, if your strings can contain commas, you could use any other character as the temporaty separator (e.g. "\n")*

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a helper function to expand the suffixes?

```
strings = [
    '9644-54-3184/5544/2583',
    'foo-bar-234/5423/12'
]

def expandsuffix(string: str) -> str:

    prefix, suffixes = string.rsplit('-', maxsplit=1)
    return ', '.join('-'.join((prefix, suffix)) for suffix in suffixes.split('/'))
      
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for string in strings:
        print(expandsuffix(string))
```

Comment: I ran the above and it returned the following error:
```ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)```